# Pubnub History response not showing published messages

Tags: android, pubnub

I am using pubnub sdk for android for chat app. I am retrieving history of a channel using pubnub.history. I getting the the response containing the received messages but response does not contain published messages. I have used .shouldstore(true) and "store and playback" enabled to true in the Pubnub dashboard.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You would need to provide sample code the reproduces the issue, the sub-key, channel name, message content, etc. Best to submit this to PubNub support since you need to provide your sub-key and you should not do in public forum. Also need to know which version of the PubNub Android SDK you are using.

Comment: Did you ever get resolution on this issue?

Comment: Still struggling with this in 2019. @Meadeveloper, did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, I did not find the solution yet